# Spring MVC using custom HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have created my own HttpServletRequest class(I override only 1 method in it) But I dont know how to make spring to use that class ?

Comment: where do you want to use it? Do you want your servlet container use you HttpServletRequest class?

Comment: It's not clear what behavior you want.

Comment: @Alexander yes I do. I want servlet to use my custom HttpServletRequest class. But I dont know how to make spring to do that.

Comment: @BalusC I just need override getInputStream metod I extended HttpServletRequest but I can use wrapper as well. I dont understand why extending would be weird.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this way
private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;

Comment: This would only work if the HttpServletRequest was a spring bean!